# How to justify construct validity when items dropped from established instrument?

Tags: survey, scales, validity

I conducted a survey in which I used the Major Depression Inventory (MDI). While analyzing this instrument (as my Depression construct) in SmartPLS, I iteratively dropped items that had non-significant (t < 1.96) or weak (b < .5) loadings on the construct. This resulted in retaining only five of the original ten items.

My Depression construct, now with only five items, shows appropriate internal (composite reliability = .882) and discriminant (square root of the AVE is much larger than the correlations, and no significant cross loadings) validity. However, a reviewer asked about the construct validity of Depression. Since the MDI has been used many times over, the reviewer's question is how can I justify that I managed to measure depression in your sample. They believe that there may have been issues in data collection (imho, there weren't), and that my measure is not either 1) reliable, and 2)a valid measure of Depression.

My first thought to address this would be to gather another survey sample using my five retained items and another proven measure of Depression, and examine the correlation between the two. High correlation would show convergent validity. However, I am hoping for a method or justification that will be less time consuming (dang deadlines). What else can I do?

Thank you in advance.